# Cors is working with IE but not working with chrome

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Cors is also enabled in the web api2.

Comment: Not enough details. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Hi Rax Weber, The above error occurs only in chrome browser. Able to hit the api from IE. Though Cors is enabled in the Web api still i am not able to hit the api in chrome. The above error is getting displayed in the chrome console.